# where to get CodeIgniter views from

Tags: templates, codeigniter

I just started using CodeIgniter I'm wondering if anyone knows where I can download pre-made views. For example right now I'm looking for an admin interface. I could write the code myself but I'm feeling lazy ;)

Is there a place where you can get pre-made templates like you can for most CMS's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well CodeIgniter isn't a CMS first off, it's a MVC framework for PHP.  If you are looking for css templates you could try a site like http://www.oswd.org/.  Or if your looking for inspiration, http://www.csszengarden.com/.

Comment: After posting this I did a search for html admin templates and found a bunch. Felt kind of stupid like I was appoching it wrong... and i was ;)

Comment: Good luck with your web project :)